# AngularJS: How to load first N JSON responses and then request rest after page render

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs

I am requesting a large JSON response from my Rails server using Angular. By default, the template will only display the first 100 rows of the response. To speed up the page load, I would like to request the first 100 JSON responses and then request the remainder once the page has finished loading.

Please note that there are currently two AJAX calls made, the first call is made and its data is passed to the second call. The second call is the response that I need to speed up and that is displayed to the user.

This is my current controller code:

```
app.controller('clientCtrl', function($scope, $http, $cookies) {
  $scope.clients = [];

  getClients()

function getClients(){
     return $http.get("http://localhost.com:3001/authenticate.json",
       {params:
          {token: $cookies.viewing
        }})
    .success(function(data, status){
      return $http.get("http://localhost.com:3001/clients",
        {params: {
          provider_id: data.user_id,
          source: "upload"
         }})
     .success(function(provider_data, status){
       applyRemoteData(provider_data);
      });
   });
 };


  function applyRemoteData(newClients) {
    $scope.clients = newClients;
  }
});
```

This is my current relevant template code:

```
 <tr ng-repeat='client in clients | limitTo:100'>
    <td>{{client.first_name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.last_name}}</td>
    <td>{{client.email}}</td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see, I filter the results and limit them to 100 (at least initially). I would like to request the first 100 so the table can load and then request the remaining JSON objects in the background (about 20K, which is taking around 6 seconds).

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's really nothing specific to AngularJS in terms of addressing your request. All you need to do is:

1. Adjust your Web service `/clients` call so it can take a range parameter.
2. Adjust your client-side code to pass in this parameter with the rest. Probably you want to make it a method parameter like `function getClients(max)`.
3. Adjust the getClients result handler callback to merge, replace, or append the resulting data. If you want to be super-efficient you should also make it authenticate only once.
4. Adjust your initial call to pass in this parameter (`getClients(100)`).
5. Make a second call to getClients with no max (0). The age-old trick is setTimeout:

   ```
   setTimeout(function() {
       // Now load the rest, but we've drawn the UI by now...
       getClients(0);
   }, 250);
   ```

You may also want to look at https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate which is a nice replacement for setTimeout. It uses various browser hacks to get a near-immediate callback if you want this to be as fast as possible.